# What equation is Statsmodels OLS using to create example fit line

Tags: python-3.x, linear-regression, statsmodels

I'm a novice to statics analysis and was looking into using statsmodels.  As part of my research I ran into the following set of [examples](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/ols.html).

The section "OLS Non-linear curve but liner in parameters" is confusing the heck out of me.  Example Follows:

```
np.random.seed(9876789)
nsample = 50
sig = 0.5
x = np.linspace(0, 20, nsample)
X = np.column_stack((x, np.sin(x), (x-5)**2, np.ones(nsample)))
beta = [0.5, 0.5, -0.02, 5.]

y_true = np.dot(X, beta)
y = y_true + sig * np.random.normal(size = nsample)

res = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
print(res.summary())
```

This shows the following summary results:

```
OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       0.933
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.928
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     211.8
Date:                Tue, 28 Feb 2017   Prob (F-statistic):           6.30e-27
Time:                        21:33:30   Log-Likelihood:                -34.438
No. Observations:                  50   AIC:                             76.88
Df Residuals:                      46   BIC:                             84.52
Df Model:                           3                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x1             0.4687      0.026     17.751      0.000       0.416       0.522
x2             0.4836      0.104      4.659      0.000       0.275       0.693
x3            -0.0174      0.002     -7.507      0.000      -0.022      -0.013
const          5.2058      0.171     30.405      0.000       4.861       5.550
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        0.655   Durbin-Watson:                   2.896
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.721   Jarque-Bera (JB):                0.360
Skew:                           0.207   Prob(JB):                        0.835
Kurtosis:                       3.026   Cond. No.                         221.
==============================================================================
```

When you plot all of this you get:
[Plot of Data, Fit and True Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQUYS.png)

What's confusing me is I can't figure out how the fit comes out of the coefficients shown in the summary table.  My understanding is that these coefficients for the linear fit should correspond to and equation in the format `X1 * x^3 + X2 * X^2 + X3 * X + Const`, but that does not result in the curve seen.  My next thought was that it might have been extrapolating the equation based on the values in the X matrix, therefore something like `X1 * x + X2 * sin(x) + X3 * (x-5)^2 + Const`.  That also does not work.

What does seem to work is a polynomial fit with a degree of around 10.  I found that using `np.polyfit(x, y, 10)`. (The Coefficients of which are not similar to the OLS ones, plus there's 6 more)

So my question is what equation is OLS using to produce the predicted values?  How doe the coefficients relate to it?  When no equation is specified (assuming it's using something different than normal polynomial equations) how does it determine what to use or whats the best fit?

One Note, I've figured out that I can force it to do what I was expecting by changing the x values used to a different matrix via np.vander()

```
X = np.vander(X, 4)
```

This produces results in line with what I was expecting and np.polyfit.